# Donde o como puedo convertir codigo SQL a MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, transact-sql

Necesito ayuda para convertir todo este codigo SQL SERVER a MYSQL para que se pueda ejecutar en mi bd de MYSQL que esta en phpmyadmin, ya que no me reconoce ese codigo el phpmyadmin.

**Dato extra:** Es un **tipo de tabla definido por el usuario** en SQL SERVER.

```
  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EstructuraCarga] AS TABLE(
  [DocumentoIdentidad] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [Nombres] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [Apellidos] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [IdEleccion] [varchar](max) NULL,
  [IdUsuarioRegistro] [varchar](max) NULL)
   GO
```

Comment: ¿Y qué hace ese código? Para traducir un lenguaje a otro al menos debes dominar el lenguaje fuente. La documentación de MySQL es bastante completa y seguramente una lectura sobre la creación de tablas te sacará de la duda. ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: De nuevo: una cosa es SQL, y otra es **SQL Server**.

Comment: Mira cualquier ejemplo de creación de tabla en MySql, y seguro que eres capaz de hacerlo por ti mismo.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Claro antes de publicar mi problema, realice diferentes lecturas, y pruebas de como tratar de convertir el codigo y tambien en el peor caso crearlo de cero por cuenta propia, pero no encuentro en MYSQL algo que se utilice " tipo de tabla definido por el usuario" que es un tabla temporal. Por ende no la puedo crear el código porque no encontré nada de como hacerlo en MYSQL, es más creo que no se puede aplicar en MYSQL. Algún experto que me ayude por favor.

Comment: Por casualidad leiste esta respuesta [create-type-on-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266101/create-type-on-mysql)?

Comment: @jojojo Lo siento, pensé que era un simple CREATE TABLE. Me disculpo.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede realizar dicha creación en MYSQL, se tiene que usar otro gestor de base de datos que admita la creación "Tipos de tabla definido por el usuario".(ORACLE DB, etc)